# oracle PL/SQL error received

Tags: oracle, plsql

I receive an error when I compile this PL/SQL block in ORACLE SQL builder

This could be a silly error, but I am stuck, honestly

```
DECLARE
First_name varchar2(30);
Last_Name varchar2(30);
Con_flag constant NUMBER:=0;
BEGIN
  select FNAME,LNAME 
  into First_name,Last_Name
  from customer where ROLLCALL=1;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee Name'||First_name||' '||Last_Name);
END;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Employee not found');
END;
```

Error received is

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
DECLARE
First_name varchar2(30);
Last_Name varchar2(30);
Con_flag constant NUMBER:=0;
BEGIN
  select FNAME,LNAME 
  into First_name,Last_Name
  from customer where ROLLCALL=1;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee Name'||First_name||' '||Last_Name);
END;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Employee not found');
END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 11, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" 
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `END;` before `EXCEPTION` should not be there. The exception block is part of the begin-end block, so the second `END` is the only one you need.

Comment: It worked, but I wonder why the output does not show what I am printing

Comment: I had missed this SET SERVEROUTPUT ON